# Customize selection for collection of elements - Selenide

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selector, selenide

How can I select the on of element, and this element contains a collection of elements, How can I select or pass through this element's collection?

- the default search method `WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElements(By.tagName("*"));`
  is `$$("*")`
  they consider that default space to search is the whole document, how can I specify the region to search? Assume that I need the **a** tags from the region or from specific element.

I have the following schema for my page:

```
  <div class="class1"> 
     <a href=""  />
     <a href=""  />
     <img src="img.png" /> 
  </div>
  <a href=""  />
  <a href=""  />
  <div class="class2"> 
     <a href=""  />
     <div class="class4"> <div>
   </div>
```

How can I pass all elements of **div class="class1"**, ex: after select **div.class1** element, I need to see all elements inside this **div**.

Answer (score 1):

You should find first div class="class1" then using this object find all element under this like below code:

```
WebElement el = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElement(By.className("class1"));
List<WebElement> elements =  el.findElements(By.tagName("*"));
```

Let me know if this will not work!!!

Thanks
Sadik

Comment: hey is it el.findElement or el.findElements ?

Comment: Updated findElements